# Significato di "ti spacco la brocca"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms, regional

Ho sentito (ma non ne sono certo al 100%) questa espressione, pronunciata con tono rabbioso da un romano:

> Ti [o vi] spacco la brocca!

“Perdere la brocca” e “sbroccare” si usano col significato di “perdere la testa”, per cui suppongo che l'espressione riportata abbia il significato di “ti [o vi] spacco la testa”, ma non l'ho mai sentita prima d'ora. Qualcuno mi sa dire il significato di questa espressione, quantomeno a Roma, oppure mi sa dire un'espressione foneticamente molto simile che posso avere confuso con questa?

Answer (score 4):

Da [Il dizionario del dialetto romanesco](http://www.theromanpost.com/2016/06/dizionario-dialetto-romanesco/)

> 265. Brocca : Testa, da cui sbroccà = andar fuori di testa [A].

Quindi ti spacco la brocca, ti spacco la testa.

Comment: Da romano, quel sito mi sembra un po' abborracciato, come se avessero messo insieme qualcosa di orecchiato, qualcosa di più serio, qualcosa boh. In particolare, non ho presente “brocca” in questo senso (ma ovviamente non vuol dire nulla), né lo riporta il _Dizionario romanesco_ di Fernando Ravaro, che per “brocca” dà solo il senso che ha anche in italiano e, al plurale, quello di “mammelle femminili”. D'altro canto, il De Mauro registra anche “roman., gerg., testa” (https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/brocca).